# texture overwrite

Tags: opengl

I find this problem when I try to render multiple textures in a 3D model. I find the textures loaded later is overwriting the ones loaded earlier(say while doing a perspective projection ).Some of the textures are transparent. Is there any way one can get around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Some more clarification on the problem would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem then the only solution is to break the model up into parts, sort the parts by the distance from the camera and draw them back to front. 
Once you have drawn a primitive, it's drawn - using a depth buffer can reject pixels if they are further away than the previously drawn primitive at that position but it doesn't help for transparent primitives.